# convert seconds into date in jquery,not working in IE using new Date("number of seconds")

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using a calendar,but in IE 
eventStartDay =  new Date(eventStart.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000*(days)));
is not working.
I have replacer new Date with function parseISO8601("yyyy-mm-dd")
but i dont know how to get a date using only seconds

Comment: More info that would be nice: Version of IE, value of `eventStart`, value of `days`, actual error message or result of `eventStartDay`, ...

Comment: Your code should be creating and returning a `Date` object whose value is the value of the `eventStart` `Date` object's value plus `days` days, on IE and elsewhere. And does, for me: http://jsbin.com/umimok It has an unnecessary set of parens (around `days`), but they're harmless and otherwise it's fine.

Comment: IE version 8
eventStart is the variable in which i want to move the date
days is a whole number like 2 or three 
days is the difference between two days,which are start times of two events.
error message in IE is NaN
This works fine in Firefox

Comment: @NidhinBosej.: That suggests that `days` is `NaN`, or that `eventStart`'s underlying value is `NaN` (which it can be, if you try to parse an invalid date). So use a debugger (IE8 and above have one built in) to inspect those variables.

Comment: eventStart is NaN.
days i get as a whole number as i can see in the debugger

Comment: @NidhinBosej.: Okay, so I guessed right -- see the answer I was posting while you checked. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the following formats are  supported across all browsers and so i used the ones among them so that it wont crash in any of the browser.

```
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd  
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy"  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"  
var d = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds  
var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said you're getting `NaN` as a result. That tells us that either `days` is `NaN`, or that `eventStart`'s underlying value is `NaN`.

My guess is that you're asking the `Date` constructor to parse a string for you, putting the result in `eventStart`, and not checking whether that worked. The only string formats *documented* as being supported by [`new Date(string)`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) are:

1. Whatever `Date#toString` spits out (which is not defined, but must be accepted on input),
2. A simplified form of ISO-8601 (not necessarily supported in older browsers, new in ES5)

...but in practice, all modern browsers (including IE) will also let you use the format `"yyyy/mm/dd"`.

So I suspect you may be trying to parse a date string that isn't supported in the version of IE you're testing with. For instance, IE8 and earlier can't handle `"yyyy-mm-dd"` (IE9 can) even though they're happy with `"yyyy/mm/dd"`.

So I suspect that's the issue you're running into, `eventStart` is actually invalid to start with, which taints the entire calculation. Fixing it may be as simple as doing a `.replace(/-/g, "/")` on the string beforehand. If your format is more complex than `yyyy-mm-dd`, you might look at a library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) or similar.